# Convert Local time to UTC and vice versa

Tags: java, android, time

I'm working on Android application, and I want to convert local time (device time) into UTC and save it in database. After retrieving it from database I have to convert it again and display in the device's time zone.  Can anyone suggest how to do this in Java?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I converted local time to GMT/UTC and vice versa using these two methods and this works fine without any problem for me.

```
public static Date localToGMT() {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date gmt = new Date(sdf.format(date));
    return gmt;
}
```

pass the GMT/UTC date which you want to convert into device local time to this method:

```
public static Date gmttoLocalDate(Date date) {

    String timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
    Date local = new Date(date.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(date.getTime()));
    return local
}
```

Comment: new Date(String date) is deprecated. You should not use it!

Comment: You can use DateFormat.parse(String date) instead of  new Date(String date) as it is deprecated.

Comment: The terribly flawed date-time classes seen here are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I used this code to change the UTC which is returned by the Alarm Manager of the Android system to IST. Everything is just the same only change the timezone string value to "IST" directly without getting it from the Calendar because it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 31):

A simplified and condensed version of the accepted answer:

```
public static Date dateFromUTC(Date date){
    return new Date(date.getTime() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(new Date().getTime()));
}

public static Date dateToUTC(Date date){
    return new Date(date.getTime() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(date.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this one's a simple one liner proper answer, good one buddy.

Comment: but TimeZone#getOffset() accepts the time in UTC...

Comment: I suggested an edit, but it has been rejected, the first function (i.e. `dateFromUTC`) has a bug. If the input `date` parameter is in UTC we must add the time difference of the local time to reach the local time. Then it must be like this `return new Date(date.getTime() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(new Date().getTime()));`.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:
 //convert to UTC to Local format

```
 public Date getUTCToLocalDate(String date) {
            Date inputDate = new Date();
            if (date != null && !date.isEmpty()) {
                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                try {
                    inputDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return inputDate;
        }
```

//convert Local Date to UTC

```
public String getLocalToUTCDate(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date time = calendar.getTime();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return outputFmt.format(time);
}
```

Comment: This is a working solution.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or, ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture current moment as seen in a particular time zone.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Make an `OffsetDateTime` object to exchange with the database.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;  // Write moment to database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;  // Retrieve a moment from database.
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;  // Adjust into a particular tim zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time*;classes that years ago supplanted the terrible date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Store in a database using a driver complaint with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Generate text to present to user.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.getDefault() ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

An implementation of *java.time* is built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, the [latest tooling brings most of the functionality](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) via “API desugaring”. If that does not work for you, use the *ThreeTenABP* library to get most of the *java.time* functionality that was back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Comment: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21): `java.time.OffsetDateTime#now`

Comment: @yozhik No, that is no longer true. See the edits to my last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

you may try something like this to insert into DB:

```
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a E zz");
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
    String dd = f.format(new Date());
```

This opt from ur comment:

**OUTPUT:**

> 1:43 PM Mon UTC

For this, -> convert it again and display in the device's time

**UPDATE:**

```
String dd = f.format(new Date());

        Date date = null;
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a E zz");
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(dd);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 7:30 PM Mon GMT+05:30

U may display like this.

Comment: it shows null pointer exception while trying to convert it again

Comment: not possible, i have tried and works good. can u give me stack trace of ur app

Comment: i just initialized Date date = new Date() and its working fine thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Time.getCurrentTimezone()`

will get you the timezone and

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND)`

will get you the time in UTC in seconds. Of course you can change the value to get it in another unit.

Comment: let us say if today date is 5:34 PM Monday (IST) then how to i get it like 12:04 PM Monday (UTC)

Comment: Do you actually have access to a time object for the time you need to convert or do you just have a string?

Comment: I just have a string

Comment: @Dyo This should help you solve your problem. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
DateFormat formatterIST = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatterIST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        Date date = formatterIST.parse(formatterIST.format(dateobj));
        System.out.println(formatterIST.format(date));

        DateFormat formatterUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatterUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // UTC timezone
        System.out.println(formatterUTC.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get current UTC :

```
public String getCurrentUTC(){
        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return outputFmt.format(time);
}
```